# Unable to utilize numpad as my keyboard trigger

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to change media using Autohotkey. I want to utilize Left Shift (<+) + LWin (<#) + Numpad8. Here is my code below but it does not work. I am having issues trying to utilize my Numpad8 to change music. I already know I can use the regular numbers on top of my keyboard but I would like to utilize my numpad instead. Please advise, thanks.

```
<+<#NumPad8::
Send {Media_Next}
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the Numpad Section of the docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#numpad), they mention:

> If NumLock is OFF but Shift is pressed, the system temporarily releases Shift and acts as though NumLock is ON.

This appears to also be applicable vice versa, as holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while `Numlock` is on before clicking `NumPad8` instead appears to send `NumpadUp` instead of `Shift`+`Numpad8`.

We can work around this by creating a Hotkey to activate when Win+NumpadUp[+ any other modifier keys (such as Shift)] is pressed, and then check ourselves whether `Shift` and `Numlock` are active. If they are, then we `Send` the Media key.

Current Code:

```
*#NumPadUp::
if(GetKeyState("NumLock", "T") and GetKeyState("Shift", "P"))
    Send {Media_Next}
return
```

However, if we hold down `Win`+`Shift` while repeatedly pressing the key, it appears to revert back from `NumpadUp` to `Numpad8`. In order to account for this, we can reuse the body of the previous Hotkey in a new Hotkey that activates when `*#NumPad8` is used.

---

## Final Code:

```
*#NumPadUp::
*#NumPad8::
if(GetKeyState("NumLock", "T") and GetKeyState("Shift", "P"))
    Send {Media_Next}
return
```

Edit: Thank you [@samthecodingman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3068190/samthecodingman) for bringing up an optimization that I missed- code has been edited to include this

Comment: Surely you can just put `*#NumPadUp::` and `*#NumPad8::` together on their own lines if you are reusing their bodies.

Comment: You are right @samthecodingman, I completely forgot that I can do that to reduce redundancy- I went ahead and updated the post to include this. Thank you for bringing that up!

Comment: @Spyre Is there a reason you added the letter "T" and "P" in the code? Can we use any letter?

Comment: Good Question! When getting the keystate of ***T***oggleable keys like `Capslock` or `Numlock`, we pass `"T"` as the second parameter of the function so that AHK knows to get the current toggled state of the key (as opposed to the Physical, is the key currently pushed down, state). On the other hand, with the `Shift` key in this instance, we want to know what the ***P***hysical state of the key is, so we pass `"P"` as the second parameter for `GetKeyState`.

Comment: Note that you *can* use `GetKeyState` without the second parameter, but that returns what the Computer thinks the state of the key is (as opposed to it's Physical or Toggled state). This is not what we want for 1. `Numlock`, since we want it's Toggle state and 2. for Shift, because the weird interaction with the Numpad keys sometimes makes the computer think that the key is not held down even when it is Physically pushed down on your keyboard. For more info on `GetKeyState`, check out it's page in the AHK docs: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm. Hope this helps @Kay!